# How to change background color from black background?

Tags: javascript

I found many scripts about changing color of background, for example this one:

```
function changeBGC(color){
    document.bgColor = color;
}
```

My current HTML is:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="javascript:changeBGC('#000099')">Mouseover Blue</a>
```

It seems it's working only with a white background at the beginning, because if I set some color with CSS like:

```
body { 
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

then its not working anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the background color of body then use the following code:

```
function changeBGC(color){
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

This will change the color of background.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `background-color` style instead of using the outdated `bgColor`:

```
function changeBGC(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Note: `document` does not have a style property - see user Kolink's comment.

Comment: I don't know why this has 4 upvotes. `document` has no `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="test" ...> ... </a>
```

use jquery:

```
$("#test").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background","color");
},function(){
    $(this).css("background","#000");
});
```

Comment: Except they're trying to change the `<body>`'s background color, not the link's. If they were trying to do what you proposed, it could easily be done with **only** CSS

Comment: No offense but jQuery to change just the background ?